# Github Actions deploy artifacts

Tags: github, github-actions

Below workflow fails when deploying the artifacts to S3. In the last line, in the deployment job, it's complaining that `./build` doesn't exist, probably because it can't find the artifacts.

```
The user-provided path ./build does not exist.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 255.
```

How do I make it recognise the artifacts created in the build job?

```
name: Build and deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: |
          npm i -D
          npm test --if-present
          npm run build:prod
        env:
          CI: true
      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Deploy to S3
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        run: |
          aws s3 cp \
          --recursive \
          --acl public-read \
          --region ap-southeast-2 \
          ./build s3://example
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the artifact in the deploy job. See the [`actions/download-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) action.

```
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to S3
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        run: |
          aws s3 cp \
          --recursive \
          --acl public-read \
          --region ap-southeast-2 \
          ./build s3://example
```

Comment: Getting the error: "upload failed: <file> <bucket> Unable to locate credentials"  Are the settings in "env:" not enough?  does this truly work?